# Is it possible to define an alias for type (enum or message) in google protobuf?

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

I have two enums in my proto file which define almost the same values.

Is it possible to cut out one of them and to leave an alias to keep all the code working?

Example:

```
enum A {
   a = 0;
   b = 1;
}
enum B {
   a = 0;
   b = 1;
}
```

I want to have something like typedef in c++:

```
enum A {
   a = 0;
   b = 1;
}

typedef A B;
```

I haven't found this in documentation. Are there any workarounds ?

Comment: `typedef enum A {...} B;` is more succinct, and `using B = enum A {...};` should work as well if you prefer.

Comment: I swear, i need to hunt down whoever first had the idea that "smth" was an acceptable substitute for the word "something".

Comment: I'd like to see language-agnostic solution. Was googling for "protobuf type alias" for C# project and found this page only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old question, but if some people are still interested,
It is possible to create alias on enum with protobuf now

```
enum EnumAllowingAlias {
  option allow_alias = true;
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  STARTED = 1;
  RUNNING = 1;
}
enum EnumNotAllowingAlias {
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  STARTED = 1;
  // RUNNING = 1;  // Uncommenting this line will cause a compile error inside Google and a warning message outside.
}
```

As explained in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3). You just need to enable the alias option by adding `option allow_alias = true;`

Comment: Useful answer, but not for the question asked. The question is about `typedef` for the whole enum type, this answer is about aliasing same numeric value inside one enum.

Answer (score 6):

As of protobuf version 3, this is not possible.

Comment: Seems that this is no longer correct, according to proto3 docs.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum