# Is there thrift support for alias

Tags: communication, thrift, thrift-protocol

This question is similar to [Is it possible to define an alias for type (enum or message) in google protobuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533549/is-it-possible-to-define-an-alias-for-type-enum-or-message-in-google-protobuf)

But I want to know if thrift supports similar function. I couldnt find any such in documentation.

I want to write something like the following in thrift

```
enum EnumAllowingAlias {
  option allow_alias = true;
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  STARTED = 1;
  RUNNING = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thrift does indeed support typedefs. IMHO the Thrift IDL is one of the most elegant out there. Here's a couple typedef examples:

```
ubuntu@Kassarat:~$ cat test.thrift
struct ICRFPosition {
    1: double right_ascension
    2: double declination
    3: optional i16 ecliptic_year
}

typedef ICRFPosition ICRFP

enum RadioObservationSystem {
    Parkes  = 1
    Arecibo = 2
    GMRT    = 17
    LOFAR   = 18
    Socorro = 25
    VLBA    = 51
}

typedef RadioObservationSystem ROS
ubuntu@Kassarat:~$ docker run -v ~:/data apache/thrift -o /data --gen cpp /data/test.thrift
ubuntu@Kassarat:~$ grep "ICRFP;" gen-cpp/*
gen-cpp/test_types.h:typedef class ICRFPosition ICRFP;
ubuntu@Kassarat:~$ grep "ROS;" gen-cpp/*
gen-cpp/test_types.h:typedef RadioObservationSystem::type ROS;
ubuntu@Kassarat:~$
```

Comment: Stole most of the above from here: https://github.com/RandyAbernethy/ThriftBook/blob/master/part2/types/complex/radio_observation.thrift

Comment: ICRFP  is the alias for ICRFPosition right? I am looking for a alias to say GMRT here. Not the full enum/struct

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question through the link. This is not an answer to what you are asking I leave this in case it helps someone and update the answer.